# C# query an XML file

Tags: c#, xml

If we look at the XML sample from [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387034.aspx) 
What kind of query do I need in order to obtain the element value `zip = 98112` for  `PurchaseOrderNumber="99505"` where the address type is `Billing`?

I tried using `System.Xml.Linq` and `System.Xml.XPath` working to modify the sample codes from Microsoft, but I just can't do it.

The code I made (and obviously doesn't work) is:

```
XElement root = XElement.Load(@"C:\Projects\XML_Tutorial\PurchaseOrders.xml");

IEnumerable<XElement> po =
        from el in root.Elements("PurchaseOrder")
        where //(string)el.Attribute("PurchaseOrderNumber") == "99503" &&
           (from add in root.Descendants("Address") // either use root.Descendants or el.Elements
            where (string)add.Attribute("Type") == "Billing" &&
                  (string)el.Attribute("PurchaseOrderNumber") == "99505"
            select add)
            .Any()
        select el;

foreach (XElement el in po)
    textBox1.AppendText((string)el.Value + System.Environment.NewLine);
```

When using this code, I get the result:

```
"Cristian Osorio456 Main StreetBuffaloNY98112USACristian Osorio456 Main StreetBuffaloNY98112USAPlease notify me before shipping.Power Supply145.99"
```

Comment: Update your question and show us the code you've tried. It's better to show what mistakes you've made.

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must **describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it** — in the question itself. See [SSCCE.org for guidance](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Can you convert this xml in DataTable, if yes, then you can achieve your task by Table.Select() method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said you need the `<zip>` element, but your query returns entire `<PurchaseOrder>`, because you return `el`.

I prefer method-based queries when dealing with LINQ to XML:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("Input.xml");

var zip = doc.Root
             .Elements("PurchaseOrder")
             .FirstOrDefault(o =>
                  (int)o.Attribute("PurchaseOrderNumber") == 99505)
             .Elements("Address")
             .FirstOrDefault(a => (string)a.Attribute("Type") == "Billing")
             .Element("Zip");

var zipValue = (int)zip;
```

I assumed there is only one `address` with `type` set to `Billing`. If that's not true, you can slightly modify the query:

```
var zips = doc.Root
              .Elements("PurchaseOrder")
              .FirstOrDefault(o => (int)o.Attribute("PurchaseOrderNumber") == 99505)
              .Elements("Address")
              .Where(a => (string)a.Attribute("Type") == "Billing")
              .Select(a => a.Element("Zip"));
```

`zips` will be `IEnumerable<XElement>` so you can use `foreach` to print all them out to console:

```
foreach (var zipElement in zips)
    Console.WriteLine((int)zipElement);
```

Comment: Marcin, you made it look too easy :) Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: @Nick_F You're welcome! After a while you see that LINQ is easy, but also very powerful tool.

Answer (score 0):

Here are another two approaches for writing the same query:

First Approach:

```
var zip = xDoc.Descendants("PurchaseOrder")
              .Where(el => el.Attribute("PurchaseOrderNumber")
              .Value == "99505").Descendants("Address")
              .Single(el => el.Attribute("Type").Value == "Billing")
              .Element("Zip");
```

Second Approach:

```
var zip = xDoc.Descendants("Address")
              .Single(el => el.Parent.Attribute("PurchaseOrderNumber").Value == "99505" && el.Attribute("Type").Value == "Billing")
              .Element("Zip");
```

Note that I'm assuming that only one Billing address exists. Also instead of `Single()` you can use `First`.

Comment: You should really not use `Descendants` method like that. It's inefficient.